# Mobile Detect error too many redirects

Tags: php, html

I am using a plugin which detects if the device is mobile or any pc 
so here is the **CODE**

```
require_once ('Mobile-Detect-2.8.27/Mobile_Detect.php');

$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).


if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
}else{
header("Location:../login");
}
// Any tablet device.
if( $detect->isTablet() ){
}
else{
header("Location:../login");
}

// Exclude tablets.
if( $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() ){
}else{  
header("Location:../login");
}

// Check for a specific platform with the help of the magic methods:
if( $detect->isiOS() ){
}else{
header("Location:../login");
}

if( $detect->isAndroidOS() ){
}else{
header("Location:../login");
}
```

This redirects as you can see to another page.
But when i use this my phone,Chrome shows a error 

***THIS PAGE ISN'T WORKING 

Redirect too many times***
What can be wrong ?

Comment: This message shows loop in your code. Double check it

Comment: @MehdiHosseinzadeh I myself don't see any loops. The code is above you can see it there

Comment: Debugging partial code is not possible. Try adding log to you code and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Everyone but I got the answer and I was my mistake and stupidity. Actually when the plugin detects the device as mobile then it redirects to the mobile version of the app then the mobile version of the app had another plugin which detected any computer so it was altered to detect phones now when it comes to the mobile version then it goes to computer version then to mobile and so on. So I'm sorry for my mistake and thanks everyone for helping

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to no output before any header and use `exit;` after each header

```
  header("Location:../login");
  exit;
```